# Initialize object parameters with variables

Tags: python, object, sqlalchemy

I need to insert a table object into a database with sqlalchemy. I create a like this.

```
table_entry = Exampletable()
table_entry.key = 'key'
table_entry.date = datetime.today()
table_entry.value = 'value'
dba.session.merge(table_entry)
```

That was to clarify, why i need this object parameter names.
I have a Table with 12 columns. 1 for every month. 
The columns go like this:

MONTH_1

MONTH_2

MONTH_3

MONTH_4

MONTH_5

...

if possible i want something like this.

```
table_entry = Exampletable()
table_entry.key = 'key'
month_parameter = ('MONTH_'+str(month))
table_entry.month_parameter = variable #based on another programm
```

Is it possible to initialize an object parameter this way?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want `table_entry.month_parameter` to equal `MONTH_10`, but you only want to pass `10` to it?

Comment: I want table_entry.month_parameter to equal table_entry.MONTH_10 or table_entry.MONTH_11 ... based on the current month. And than i want to pass a variable to it, that is based on another programm.

Comment: Ok so I understand this as: you want 'table_entry.MONTH_10' to be an `attribute` on `Exampletable` and you want to be able to set the value of this attribute, and you want this to be done dynamically, based on whatever the current month is

Comment: Yes exactly. I solved the problem with `setattr(my_table, key, self.dict[key])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't necessarily recommend that you do it like this (it would for example make much more sense to just store the data in a data structure like a dictionary or dataframe), but to achieve what you are asking, the following would work:

```
import datetime

class ExampleTable():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_value_of_current_month(self, value):
        month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m")
        setattr(self, "MONTH_" + month, value)


my_table = ExampleTable()

my_table.set_value_of_current_month(12345)

print(my_table.MONTH_12)
```

I'm using `setattr(...)` to achieve this. Essentially, `my_table.MONTH_12 = 12345` is the same as `setattr(my_table, "MONTH_12", 12345)`

Comment: Thank you I use it this way:
I have this dictionary

{'MONAT_11': 32983, 'MONAT_10': 36651}

and now i can just use this code:

`for key in self.dict:
  setattr(my_table, key, self.lfddict[key])`

Comment: If this solves your problem then please accept the answer